# Try to do a migration

Tags: php, sql, mysql, symfony, migration

This is my error

```
[notice] Migrating up to DoctrineMigrations\Version20231003115032
[error] Migration DoctrineMigrations\Version20231003115032 failed during Execution. Error: "An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[22004]: Null value not allowed: 1138 Invalid use of NULL value"

In ExceptionConverter.php line 114:
                                                                                                                          
  An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[22004]: Null value not allowed: 1138 Invalid use of NULL value  
                                                                                                                          

In Exception.php line 28:
                                                                           
  SQLSTATE[22004]: Null value not allowed: 1138 Invalid use of NULL value  
                                                                           

In Connection.php line 70:
                                                                           
  SQLSTATE[22004]: Null value not allowed: 1138 Invalid use of NULL value
```

I just added

```
cascade: ["persist"]
```

In my orders Entity

```
#[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'orders', targetEntity: OrdersDetails::class, cascade: ["persist"], orphanRemoval: true)]
private $ordersDetails;
```

And i have to do a doctrine:migration:migrate otherwise my site will not work.

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace DoctrineMigrations;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Schema;
use Doctrine\Migrations\AbstractMigration;

/**
 * Auto-generated Migration: Please modify to your needs!
 */
final class Version20231003115032 extends AbstractMigration
{
    public function getDescription(): string
    {
        return '';
    }

    public function up(Schema $schema): void
    {
        // this up() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE categories DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_3AF34668727ACA70');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE categories ADD CONSTRAINT FK_3AF34668727ACA70 FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES categories (id)');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE users CHANGE reset_token reset_token VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL');
    }

    public function down(Schema $schema): void
    {
        // this down() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE categories DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_3AF34668727ACA70');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE categories ADD CONSTRAINT FK_3AF34668727ACA70 FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES categories (id) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE users CHANGE reset_token reset_token VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL');
    }
}
```

I added a default null in my users entity for reset_token table to, and it's already defined like that in my db. I think it's because of this but i'm not sure .

Comment: You are changing some columns to be non nullable. You need to make sure no row already has `NULL` for this column. Otherwise you're gonna get the error you are facing right now.

Comment: thank you, i don't know if is the right solution but i just remove the NOT NULL, in the last line of the function row and even if the problem persists on my site, the migration worked.

Comment: Do you have maybe some already existing rows in database with this column to NULL. If yes, Doctrine will not be able to change has you already have NULL value for a NOT NULLABLE column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the series of events:

1. You have an optional field.
2. You add records where that field is blank.
3. You make the field mandatory.

   ```
   ALTER TABLE users CHANGE reset_token reset_token VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
   ```

You can't have a blank mandatory field, thus the error.

You have a few alternatives here:

- Set a default value at field level.

  ```php
  @ORM\Column(name="reset_token", type="string", length=100, nullable=false, options={"default" : "blah blah blah"})
  ```
- Figure out an appropriate value for existing records and update it before altering the table:

  ```sql
  $this->addSql('UPDATE users SET reset_token = (/* maybe some complex expression*/);
  ```
- Delete existing records:

  ```sql
  $this->addSql('DELETE FROM users WHERE reset_token IS NULL');
  ```

In general terms, there's no good or bad approach, it all depends on your particular business rules. Judging by the table and column names, I suspect that you don't want the field to be mandatory in the first place, since users aren't expected to have a reset token unless they want to reset their password. But I'm just speculating, I don't know what you use the column for.

Comment: I ended up solving the problem and your analysis was correct, thank you for your feedback